# Shading an area

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the best way to shade the area as indicated in the image below?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (10, 10);
\draw (0, 10) arc (90 : 0 : 10);
\draw (0, 10) arc (180 : 360 : 5);
\draw (0, 10) arc (90 : -90 : 5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for completeness: without overpainting things in white, so this works also if you have something in the background and/or if you have nontrivial opacities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (10, 10);
\begin{scope}
\draw[clip] (0, 10) arc (180 : 360 : 5);
\fill[red] (0, 10) arc (90 : 0 : 10) -- (0,0) arc(-90:90:5);
\end{scope}
\draw (0, 10) arc (90 : 0 : 10);
\draw (0, 10) arc (90 : -90 : 5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the red area is printed in top of the arc. Using `\clip (0, 10) arc (180 : 360 : 5);` within the `scope` and drawing the arc afterwards solves this issue.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, you are right. The alternative is to use `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` and `\scoped[on background layer]` as in Henri's very nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `fillbetween` library from `pgfplots`, but hopefully there is a better solution because this is painfully slow.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (10, 10);
    \draw[name path=A] (0, 10) arc (90 : 0 : 10);
    \draw[name path=B] (0, 10) arc (180 : 360 : 5);
    \draw[name path=C] (0, 10) arc (90 : -90 : 5);

    \path[intersection segments={of=A and B,sequence={A1 -- B1[reverse]}},name path=D];
    \scoped[on background layer]
        \fill[red, intersection segments={of=C and D,sequence={A1 -- B1[reverse]}}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not too bad. Takes less than a second to compile on my computer.